# Badge disappearing

Tags: support, badges

I received 2 badges in a short period (Peer Pressure and Good Question).
But I don't see them on my profile at the same time.

For example: I click on the "You've earned the "Good Question" badge" button in the achievements drop down menu and see on my profile 1 silver badge and 4 bronze.

When  I click on the "You've earned the "Peer Pressure" badge" button in the achievements drop down menu and see on my profile 0 silver badges and 5 bronze.

Has anyone experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have two different profiles: one for Stack Overflow and one for *Meta* Stack Overflow. While your reputation here on Meta is inherited from your main Stack Overflow account, *your badges are not*.

You earned Peer Pressure [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4358134/call-me).

You earned Good Question [on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4358134/call-me).

So no, you won't see both of them listed because you are following different links for each of those badges.

Comment: Just a quick question, I don't receive my +2 rep after I accept your answer. Is this a "real" bug or also something I don't know about stackoverflow?

Comment: You don't earn reputation here on Meta.